# Call function with and without UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, ios8, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a simple game as part of my efforts to learn Swift. At the end of a round, I've used a `UIGestureRecognizer` to clear a modal/hudview which, upon clearing, also clears the game board. I'd like to call the `clearBoard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)` function within the `restart()` function as well, but can't due to the necessity of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` argument to `clearBoard()`.

How can I use the `clearBoard` function with both the gesture recognizer and within the `restart` function? Simplified code below:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  // Setup views etc.  

  func endGame() {
    let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    if winner == 1 {
        self.playerScore++
        self.playerScoreLabel.text = String(self.playerScore)
        let hudView: HudView = HudView.hudInView(self.view, message: "Player won!", animated: true)

        tapRec.addTarget(self.view, action: "clearBoard")
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)



    } else {
        self.computerScore++
        self.computerScoreLabel.text = String(self.computerScore)
        let hudView: HudView = HudView.hudInView(self.view, message: "Computer won!", animated: true)

    }
}

  func restart() {
    // Restart

    // Problem here
    self.clearBoard()
  }

  func clearBoard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Clear board
  }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to set the recognizer as parameter. That's only a possibility, which apple offers you. You also can pass no parameter like that:

```
func clearBoard(){
  //Clear board
}
```

It will work with the gesture recognizer as well. You don't have to change anything in your gesture-code:

```
tapRec.addTarget(self.view, action: "clearBoard")
```

That's absolutely fine.

Comment: Thanks. I must be having another problem. I keep getting an `2015-02-25 17:29:28.602 SwiftTacToe[11122:2757435] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView clearBoard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17419e5e0` error

Comment: That means that you have a IBOutlet in your Storyboard which you dont have in your code anymore. Just click on the viewcontroller and then in the right column on the right arrow. Then where you see an "!", remove the outlet from the list.